# Scrollable div in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm to build a calendar web application. For that I need a week view, showing all events on that week. My go to reference is Google Calendar because the design is modern and is composed really well. So for the application I'm using React with redux as state management. But I seem to have run in to a problem that has been bugging me for a while now. Getting the scroll to work as the scroll in Google calendar week view, (Vertical scroll that is).

The important components:
**Lowest level component (name: body)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, withWidth, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import moment from 'moment';
import {
    weekHeadMaxWidthXl,
    weekHeadMinWidthXl,
    weekHeadMaxWidthLg,
    weekHeadMinWidthLg,
    weekHeadMaxWidthMd,
    weekHeadMinWidthMd,
    weekHeadMaxWidthSm,
    weekHeadMinWidthSm,
    weekHeadMaxWidthXs,
    weekHeadMinWidthXs,
    weekHeadHightXl
} from '../../../util/dimension';
const style = theme => ({
    bodyContainer: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        overflow: "auto",
        width: "100%",
    },
    hourContainer: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        marginTop: 1,
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xl')]: {
            maxWidth: weekHeadMaxWidthXl,
            minWidth: weekHeadMinWidthXl,
            width: "100%",
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('lg')]: {
            maxWidth: weekHeadMaxWidthLg,
            minWidth: weekHeadMinWidthLg,
            width: "100%",
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('md')]: {
            maxWidth: weekHeadMaxWidthMd,
            minWidth: weekHeadMinWidthMd,
            width: "100%",
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('sm')]: {
            maxWidth: weekHeadMaxWidthSm,
            minWidth: weekHeadMinWidthSm,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#"
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xs')]: {
            maxWidth: weekHeadMaxWidthXs,
            minWidth: weekHeadMinWidthXs,
            width: "100%",
        },

    },
    hour: {
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xl')]: {
            maxHeight: "50px",
            height: "46px",
            minHeight: "44px",
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('lg')]: {
            maxHeight: "50px",
            height: "46px",
            minHeight: "44px",
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('md')]: {
            maxHeight: "50px",
            height: "46px",
            minHeight: "44px",
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('sm')]: {
            maxHeight: "50px",
            height: "46px",
            minHeight: "44px",
        },
        borderBottom: "solid 1px #e7e7e7",
        borderLeft: "solid 1px #e7e7e7",
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
    },
    offset: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        paddingTop: 10,
        backgroundColor: "#FFF",
        borderBottom: "solid 1px #e7e7e7",
        borderTop: "solid 1px #e7e7e7",
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xl')]: {
            maxWidth: 55,
            minWidth: 50,
            width: 53,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('lg')]: {
            maxWidth: 53,
            minWidth: 47,
            width: 50,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('md')]: {
            maxWidth: 50,
            minWidth: 43,
            width: 47,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('sm')]: {
            maxWidth: 47,
            minWidth: 38,
            width: 43,

        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xs')]: {
            maxWidth: 47,
            minWidth: 43,
            width: 38,
        },
    },
});

const body = props => {
    const { classes } = props;
    let days = [];
    const getHours = () => {
            let hours = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                hours.push(<div key={"hours " + i} className={classes.hour}>
                    <Typography> {i} </Typography>
                </div>)
            }
            return hours
        }
    days.push(<div key="offset" className={classes.offset}></div>)
    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        days.push(<div key={"days " + j} className={classes.hourContainer}>
        {getHours()}
        </div>)
    }

    return (<div className={classes.bodyContainer}>
        {days}
    </div>);
}

export default withWidth()(withStyles(style)(body));
```

**Component implementing body. (name: Calendar)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, Typography, TableCell } from '@material-ui/core';
import withWidth, { isWidthUp } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { changeWindowSizeAction } from '../../redux/actions/settingsActions';
import Month from './views/month/month';
import MonthOffset from './views/month/offset';
import WeekHead from './views/week/head';
import WeekBody from './views/week/body';


const styles = theme => ({
    week: {
        height: "100vh",
    },
    weekBody: {
        height: "100vh",
        overflowY: "auto"
    }
});


class Calendar extends React.Component {
    getFullDayBookings = bookings => {
        return bookings.filter(B => B.allDay);
    }
    generateComponent = (variant, props) => {
        switch (variant) {
            case "month":
                return <Month onDayClick={props.onDayClick} onBookingClick={props.onBookingClick} dateNr={props.nr} day={props.day} bookings={this.formatBookings()} />
            case "week":
                return this.generateWeek()
            case "day":
                return null;
            case "agenda":
                return null;
            case "offset":
                return <MonthOffset dateNr={props.nr} variant="month" />
            default:
                return (
                    <TableCell className={props.classes.monthCell}>

                    </TableCell>
                );
        }

    }
    generateWeek = () => {
        return (<div className={this.props.classes.week}>
            <WeekHead bookings={this.formatBookings().filter(E => E.allDay)} />
            <div className={this.props.classes.weekBody}>
                <WeekBody />
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
    formatBookings = () => {
        if (this.props.bookings.length > 0) {
            return this.filterBookings(this.props.bookings, this.props.bookingFilter)
        } else {
            return [];
        }

    }
    filterBookings = (bookings, filter) => {
        if (bookings.length > 0) {
            let notToRender = Object.keys(filter).filter(F => {
                if (!filter[F]) {
                    return F;
                }
            });
            return bookings.filter(E => {
                if (notToRender.length > 0) {
                    if (notToRender.indexOf(E.room) === -1) {
                        return E
                    }
                } else {
                    return E;
                }
            });
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (this.generateComponent(this.props.variant, this.props))
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        changeWindowSize: wSize => (dispatch(changeWindowSizeAction(wSize)))
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        windowSize: state.settings.windowSize,
    }
}

export default withWidth()(withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calendar)));
```

**Component implementing Calendar (name: week)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Calendar from '../components/calendar/Calendar';
import { withStyles, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import moment from 'moment';


const styles = theme => ({

});


const testEvents = [
    { "title": "Test - NotAllDay", "id": 1, "room": "office" },
    { "title": "Test - NotAllDay", "id": 2, "room": "office" },
    { "title": "Test - Cafe", "id": 3, "room": "cafe", "allDay": true, "startDate": moment(), "endDate": moment().add(2, "days") },
    { "title": "Test - NotAllDay", "id": 11, "room": "office" }]



class Week extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <Calendar variant="week" bookings={testEvents} bookingFilter={this.props.filter}/>
    }
}


const mapStateToPops = state => ({
    currentDate: state.settings.calendarState,
    filter: state.settings.roomsRender,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

});

export default withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToPops, mapDispatchToProps)(Week));
```

**Last, Component implementing Week**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; 
import Banner from '../containers/Banner';
import Sidebar from '../containers/Sidebar';
import Month from '../containers/Month';
import Week from '../containers/Week';
import './styles.css';
const styles = theme => ({
    DisplayContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        height: "100vh"
    },
    content: {
        height: "100%",
        flex: 3,
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
    'content-left': {
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
    contentShift: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    'contentShift-left': {
        marginLeft: 240,
    },
});


class Overview extends Component {
    calendarView = () => {
        switch (this.props.calendarType) {
            case "month":
                return <Month />
            case "week":
                return <Week />
            case "day":
                return <div></div>
            case "agenda":
                return <div></div>
            default:
                return <div></div>
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { classes, theme } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.DisplayContainer}>
                <div className="Banner">
                    <Banner />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Sidebar />
                </div>
                <main className={classNames(classes.content, classes[`content-left`], {
                    [classes.contentShift]: this.props.showMenu,
                    [classes[`contentShift-left`]]: this.props.showMenu,
                })}>
                    {this.calendarView()}
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Overview.propTypes ={
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        showMenu: state.settings.showMenu,
        calendarType: state.settings.calendarType,
    }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToProps)(Overview));
```

The Month view works as it should. Tho have some bugs, but the application is long from done. So, yeah if one could point me in the direction or provide some inside knowledge, that would be great!

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Seems more of a CSS issue rather than JavaScript issue. It would be great if we can see working example

Comment: In your css: `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: @stackoverfloweth in which file ?

Comment: That should be with whatever content is currently overflowing and you want to see a scroll bar. You'll also need to make sure parent divs are height 100%

Comment: @HridayModi sorry for the delay, but if you go to projectstay.dk you'll see an example but where it does not work. The desired functionality is for the view you land on, to be as close to google calendar as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS fix:

Add this CSS to your application:

```
html, #root {
   height: 100%
}

.jss2.jss3{
   height: calc(100% - 65px);
}

.jss189 {
    height: calc(100% - 132px);
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not using css files do to the use of material-ui lib for react. So, I get that the root element has to be at 100% height. But the `.jss2.jss3` I guess that's the element height you are calculating ? And if you don't mind me asking, where does the  `65px`  come from ?

Comment: `65px` is the height of banner and `132px` is the height of header of calendar. Hence to show scroll in the body of calendar you need to give proper height to the container.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get it working unfortunately :/

Comment: @Lasse strange. Have changed it on the url you have given. And it's working perfectly. Hope that you have given `100%` height to html tag too.

Comment: Ahhh, now I get the names! It's because that you see the compiled version of the website. The names is not actually that of your example. I'll reverse engineer it a bit and get back to you.

Comment: your solution is going to work, just need to figure out a way to calc the height of the screen without using `calc`. It does not work in, inline css. But thanks for your reply !